# PyTorch Average Accuracy after each epoch

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to calculate the accuracy of the model after the end of each epoch. After each epoch I would like to calculate the accuracy over the previous epoch. The model only seems to print the  same value as the mean test error.

```py
model.eval()
for images, paths in tqdm(loader_test):
    images = images.to(device)
    targets = torch.tensor([metadata['count'][os.path.split(path)[-1]] for path in paths]) # B
    targets = targets.float().to(device)

    # forward pass:
    output = model(images) # B x 1 x 9 x 9 (analogous to a heatmap)
    preds = output.sum(dim=[1,2,3]) # predicted cell counts (vector of length B)

    # logging:
    loss = torch.mean((preds - targets)**2)
    count_error = torch.abs(preds - targets).mean()
    mean_test_error += count_error
    writer.add_scalar('test_loss', loss.item(), global_step=global_step)
    writer.add_scalar('test_count_error', count_error.item(), global_step=global_step)
    
    global_step += 1

average_accuracy = 0 
mean_test_error = mean_test_error / len(loader_test)
writer.add_scalar('mean_test_error', mean_test_error.item(), global_step=global_step)
average_accuracy += mean_test_error
average_accuracy = average_accuracy /len(loader_test)
print("Average accuracy: %f" % average_accuracy)
print("Test count error: %f" % mean_test_error)
if mean_test_error < best_test_error:
    best_test_error = mean_test_error
    torch.save({'state_dict':model.state_dict(),
                'optimizer_state_dict':optimizer.state_dict(),
                'globalStep':global_step,
                'train_paths':dataset_train.files,
                'test_paths':dataset_test.files},checkpoint_path)
```

Comment: What is the definition of accuracy for this application?

Comment: It's the prediction of the correct cell count in a microscopy image.

Comment: It is a classification task? It looks like your are using a regression model to it.

Comment: About using computer vision to count things: https://paperswithcode.com/paper/from-open-set-to-closed-set-counting-objects#code there is the paper and the code there, you can use it as inspiration to help your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF** your model is a classifier, calculating accuracy follows:

```
acc = (pred.max(dim=1) == target).float().mean()
```

Where:

```
pred.shape =  (batch_size, n_classes)
target.shape = (batch_size)
```

A similar question was asked recently: [calculate accuracy for each class using CNN and pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958248/calculate-accuracy-for-each-class-using-cnn-and-pytorch/62958517#62958517)

However, you are using MSE loss to train your network. Which is a regression loss. For classification problems CrossEntropyLoss is the GO TO option: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html

**IF** you are solving an regression task. Than usually accuracy is defined by a threshold. Predictions that are bellow a certain error from the ground truth are considered, the others arent. In this case the calculation is the following:

```
errors = (pred - target) ** 2  # Squared error
acc = (errors < threshold).float().mean()
error = errors.mean()
```

Where:

```
pred.shape = (batch_size, chanels, ...) 
target.shap = (batch_size, chanels, ...)
```

Was it something like that you were looking for?

Comment: Many Thanks for your help. I believe, the task I'm trying to solve is a regression task. Please let me know, if i am wrong. Basically, i am trying to predict the number of cells in a microscopy images. I'm providing the model with the truth ground. My code already calculate the mean test error after the end of each epoch. If i store the value of the mean test error then divide by the length(test_loader) would this not give me the overall accuracy?

Comment: @Browed1983 (if the answer is useful to you you can upvote it, if it solves your problem you can use the checkmark). Accuracy is not really well defined for regression tasks... All it has to do is to be between 0 and 100%. So you are free to define it as it is the most intuitive for your task.

Comment: Many Thanks for your help. That's really useful. If i want the accuracy across the entire model do i divide the accuracy at each epoch by the total number of epochs or the length of the dataset.